# If A has a match in B, add value correlated with B to C

Tags: excel-formula

I have three columns.

A = List of every day in a calendar year:

```
January 1, 2018
January 2, 2018
etc.
```

B = List of some dates from the year where a certain event current

```
January 5, 2018
January 12, 2018
February 1, 2018
March 12, 2018
etc.
```

C = A time value correlated with the date of the event in column B.

I want to simply apply the values in C to correlate with the right date from column A and put the value in column D.

So right now it looks like this (without column D). I want column D to look like this below. I want to have the time value applied to the right row that corresponds with the date in column A. I'm just trying to show the data spread throughout the whole year, not skipping dates when there wasn't an event like it does in columns B and C currently.

```
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Column A    |      | Column B          | Column C  | Column D  |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 1,  | 2018 | January 5, 2018   | 5 minutes | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 2,  | 2018 | January 12, 2018  | 3 minutes | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 3,  | 2018 | `February 1, 2018 | 4 minutes | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 4,  | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 5,  | 2018 |                   |           | 5 minutes |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 6,  | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 7,  | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 8,  | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 9,  | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 10, | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 11, | 2018 |                   |           | 0         |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| January 12, | 2018 |                   |           | 3 minutes |
+-------------+------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

**Original image of columns:**
[image: Current column structure]

Comment: use the formula VLOOKUP(). `=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a VLOOKUP statement in column D.

Here is an example:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:C$365,2,FALSE),0)
```

IFERROR states that if you have no entries for that date it will show 0 instead of showing an error.

A1 cell is the correlated date for this D1 cell. B1:C365 is our lookup table which looks at each B cell to find the time entry related to this row. The 2 indicates that we want the VLOOKUP to return the second column of the array which would be column C.The $s prevent the column numbers of the array from changing if the formula is pasted to different cells.

The FALSE forces VLOOKUP to find an exact match, otherwise, it will take an approximate match.

Answer (score 0):

Try **INDEX+MATCH**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),0)
```

Enter the above in Cell D1 and drag it down.

Better to replace `C:C` and `B:B` with the exact ranges instead of referencing the whole column. Make sure when using exact ranges these two range must match each other i.e. `C1:C100` VS `B1:B100` but not `C2:C100` VS `B1:B101` for instance.

[image: Solution]